# On the $\max\int_0^1 fg$ where $f$ is fixed

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function. What is the maximum of $\int_0^1 fg$ among all continuous functions $g$ with $\int_0^1 |g| = 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $M  = \|f\|_\infty$.  Note that
$$\int_0^1 f(x) g(x)\, dx \le \|f\|_\infty \|g\|_1 = M.$$
Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then choose a point $x$ so $|f(x)| = M$. Wlog, we may assume 
$f(x) = M$.  Choose an interval $I$ so that $f\ge M - \epsilon$ on $I$.

Define $g$ to be $1/|I|$ on $I$ and $0$ off $[f > 0]$; then extend this function continuously onto all of $[0,1]$ so it has values in $[0, 1/|I|]$. Then 
$$\int_0^1 f(x) g(x)\, dx \ge {1\over |I|}\int_I f(x)g(x)\, dx \ge M - \epsilon.$$
The supremum must be $M$.

If you take $f(x) = x(1-x)$, $x\in [0,1]$, you will see this supremum is not attained.

Comment: Is $g$ continuous ?

Comment: YOu can "round it off" very easily. Just taper the indicator function to zero inside of $[f > 0]$; this this is a neighborhood of $I$, the continuity is not a real issue.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** Try concentrating the *weight* of $g$ around the maximum of $|f|$. What happens then?

Comment: +1. My friend why did you delete your answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/618803/8581). :-)

Comment: @B.S. This is going to sound silly, but I find it a bit embarrasing to have the title "Cannabis Equation" as my highest-rated answer.

Comment: Please make it back. I voted it to be undeleted. Honestly, your post made me to do that animation :-)