# Cannabis Equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

How can an equation for [the following curve](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CannabisCurve.html) be derived?

[image]

$$r=(1+0.9 \cos(8 \theta)) (1+0.1 \cos(24 \theta)) (0.9+0.1 \cos(200 \theta)) (1+\sin(\theta))$$

*(From [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2B0.9+cos%288+%CE%B8%29%29+%281%2B0.1+cos%2824+%CE%B8%29%29+%280.9%2B0.1+cos%28200+%CE%B8%29%29+%281%2Bsin%28%CE%B8%29%29+polar+-pi+to+pi))*

Comment: I don't get your question? Are you looking for its equation? If so you can get it on the web. Do u waana its origin?

Comment: How do you know that it isn't hemp?

Comment: I think someone's having a little bit *too* much fun for the holidays! :-)

Comment: Too much fun?  No such thing!

Comment: This reminds me of the question about the Batman equation: Could someone make a plot of Batman smoking weed? I'll have tons of bitcoin for you.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by 'derive', but see this [implementation using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20799710/418556).

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It can be made intuitively out of the following observations:

- The function $\theta \mapsto 1 + \sin(\theta)$ has the property that it is closer to $0$ for $\theta\in [\pi,2\pi]$, and it is closest when $\theta = 3\pi / 2$. This is good for the shape you want, since you want it to be smaller on the "lower" part. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2b0.9%20cos%288%20%CE%B8%29%29%20%281%2bsin%28%CE%B8%29%29%20polar%20-pi%20to%20pi)

[image]

- Once we know this, we still have to add the *pointy* parts, you can count there are $7$ corners, right? Now, how can we make $7$ corners? Note that $\theta \mapsto 1+ 0.9 \times\cos(8\theta)$ is good in that it expands the radio when $\cos(8\theta) > 0$ and it reduces it when $\cos(8\theta) < 0$. Each corner corresponds actually to a *reduce,expand,reduce*, and $\theta \mapsto 1+ 0.9 \times\cos(8\theta)$ has exactly $8$ regions like this, but exactly one happens where $1+\sin(\theta)\approx 0$, and so we actually have $7$ such regions. See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2b0.9%20cos%288%20%CE%B8%29%29%20%20polar%20-pi%20to%20pi)

[image]

Finally, all of this points to [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2b0.9%20cos%288%20%CE%B8%29%29%20%281%2bsin%28%CE%B8%29%29%20polar%20-pi%20to%20pi)

[image]

The remaining factors, which have much smaller periods, and expand/contract the radio much less, are there just to make the "borders" looks less regular.

Comment: Now it is OK. :-)

Comment: @B.S. Actually, it doesn't let me delete because it was accepted.

Comment: I wanted it to be here accepted either. :-) +1

Answer (score 46):

You may do the same as other answer did in details by Maple:

```
[> with(plots):
  animate(polarplot, [(1+.9*cos(A*t))*(1+.1*cos(A*t))*(.9+0.5e-1*cos(A*t))*(1+sin(t)), t = -Pi .. Pi, thickness = 2], A = 0 .. 15);
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent animation +1